# Create a full screen MultiSelectListPreferece

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I would like to create a preference screen that is full screen.  The screen will contain a multiselect list.  It will also be dynamic, i.e. the list on the screen is not static and I would like to have a refresh button.  I am going to try and model it after the bluetooth preference screen in android settings (this is not multiselect so mine would have check boxes).

[image]

Basically there is some search function that will find list items and populate the list.

Can you create a preference screen (full screen) with a list preference?

or

Can you full screen a ListPreferenceDialog?  Problem I see here is that even if I full screen the dialog I would still need to get a bottom action bar for the refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

`PreferenceActivity` extends `ListActivity`. So, you can use the underlying `ListView` and bind a `ListAdapter` with whatever data you want. But if you want to do things like the Bluetooth settings, [take a look at the source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/bluetooth/BluetoothDevicePreference.java). Basically they're calling `PreferenceGroup.addPreference` each time a new Bluetooth device is found.

Comment: For some reason I cannot scroll the list view.  I ask if it can scroll and it says no.  I bound a simple ArrayAdapter to the preference activities listview.  Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Bluetooth settings was just a good example of how I wanted my layout to look.  In my case I am going to deal with a multi select list.  Its still unclear how I could deal with this even when I get scroll working, but first things first ;)